# Sparql: Use DBpedia together with PeriodicTable.owl

Tags: sparql, owl, dbpedia

I use the periodicTable.owl from http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/. Each chemical element has a name e.g. "helium". I am now trying to gather more information about an element from dbpedia via the rdfs:label.

I tried this as an example:

```
PREFIX table: <http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?element ?abstract
WHERE
     {
        ?element rdf:type table:Element .
        ?element table:name ?name .
        ?dbr rdfs:label ?name .
        OPTIONAL{?dbr dbo:abstract ?abstract} .
     }
```

So the idea is to connect each of the elements in the periodictable to the corresponding dbpedia resource via the rdfs:label property and return the abstract if there is one like here: https://dbpedia.org/page/Helium

This does not work. Any suggestions why?

Comment: did you load both, DBpoedia and the small OWL file into your own triple store?

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable.owl, the names are literals with the datatype `xsd:string`. In DBpedia (at least in this case), the labels are literals with the datatype `rdf:langString` + a language tag.

These three labels have the same lexical form, but they are different literals (see [Literal Equality](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#section-Literal-Equality)):

```
ex:Someting rdfs:label "Foo" . # xsd:string
ex:Someting rdfs:label "Foo"@en . # rdf:langString + language tag "en"
ex:Someting rdfs:label "Foo"@fr . # rdf:langString + language tag "fr"
```

To compare their lexical forms, you can use SPARQL’s [`str()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) in a `FILTER`:

```
# untested query

SELECT ?element ?abstract
WHERE {

  ?element_daml
    a table:Element ;
    table:name ?name_daml .

  OPTIONAL { 

    ?element_dbpedia 
      rdfs:label ?name_dbpedia .
      dbo:abstract ?abstract . 

    FILTER( ?name_daml = str(?name_dbpedia) ) .

  }

}
```

Notes:

- You might get better performance by using a subquery.
- You might want to add a triple pattern to restrict which DBpedia entities are searched.
- If you want to compare the labels case-insensitive, you can use [`LCASE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-lcase)/[`UCASE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#func-ucase).

Comment: I assume that the TO hasn't loaded both datasets into the same triple store, thus, I'd also suggest to check for the need of a federated query to the DBpedia endpoint.